# List of Strings from Random Panda Dataframe Data

Tags: python

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns, Latitude and Longitude. I am trying to pull random sets of coordinates and turning them into a list of strings, which will then be used for testing.

My goal is to get a list where each element has the following format:
'34.30125,-118.45398', for example.

I can get this to work with a for loop, as follows:

```
coords = np.random.randint(len(df), size=100)
addresses=list()
for coord in coords:
    addresses.append ((str (df.iloc[coord, 0])) + ',' + (str (df.iloc[coord, 1]))
```

)

This works, but I imagine there is a vectorized version of this code that I could use. Here is my attempt at it:

```
coords = np.random.randint(len(df), size=100)
addresses = (str (df.iloc[coords, 0].values)) + ',' + (str (df.iloc[coords, 1].values))
```

This doesn't work, as the result is a list with all latitudes first, and then all longitudes. Here is an example of the incorrect output:

```
'[33.96112 33.97383 33.99947 33.97956 34.15354 34.17544 33.73047 34.22336\n 34.07459 34.17304 34.25057 34.2081  34.20415 34.12729 33.97265 34.03505\n 34.09874 33.93781 33.78685 34.14127 34.04642 34.09625 34.24176 33.99518\n 34.05084 33.96508 34.27572 34.06566 33.76407 34.04516 34.039   34.06713],[-118.28861 -118.27594 -118.47455 -118.32636 -118.58882 -118.45547\n -118.28534 -118.53631 -118.36987 -118.37825 -118.60866 -118.62045\n -118.58971 -118.18886 -118.30977 -118.23742 -118.207   -118.24166\n -118.29918 -118.4998  -118.29458 -118.35162 -118.4445  -118.29393\n -118.51866 -118.40532 -118.45647 -118.30053 -118.26663 -118.49858 ]'
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. Just remove the reference to the column when using `iloc` and add a `tolist()` function:

```
coords = np.random.randint(len(df), size=100)
addresses = ((df.iloc[coords].values).tolist())
```

When it comes to converting your result into a string, you have two options:

1 - Turn the whole thing into a single string:

```
myPrettyString = (",".join(map(str, addresses)))
```

2 - Turn each of its item into a separate string. In this case, we will make a list of strings using list comprehension:

```
list=[]
list+=[str(i) for i in addresses]
```

Comment: This little guy should do the trick for you: `irinasstring = (",".join(map(str, addresses)))`

Comment: You could also use list comprhension to turn each pair into a separate string: `list=[];
list+=[str(i) for i in addresses]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[34.30125, 34.22328], 'long': [-118.45398, -118.48269]})    
df =
    lat          long
0   34.30125    -118.45398
1   34.22328    -118.48269

coords = np.random.randint(len(df), size=100)
df =df.astype(str)
addresses = df.iloc[coords, 0] + ',' + df.iloc[coords, 1]
addresses.values.tolist()
```

**Output**

```
['34.30125,-118.45398', '34.22328,-118.48269']
```